# Need help understanding the proof: if v is a left singular vector of A then v is a unit eigenvector of $AA^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is the proof in my textbook:

[image]

What I don't understand it why " $AA^{T}u = 0u $ means that u is an eigenvector.

Is this a theorem that I don't know? That if you multiply a matrix by a vector and it's 0, then that vector is an eigenvector?

Further, we are asked to prove that u is a *unit* eigenvector. The answer only proves that it is an eigenvector. How do we show that it is a *unit* eigenvector?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. From $AA^T u = 0u$ we can conclude that $u$ is an eigenvector of $AA^T$ by the definition of eigenvector. Also, $u$ is not necessarily a unit vector from that proof, but without loss of generality it can be rescaled to be unit length. I'm assuming here that your vectors are over the real or complex numbers.

Comment: If $Cu=0u$ and $u\ne\vec{0}$, then u is an eigenvector for C corresponding to the eigenvalue 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write my SVD notation as $A=U \Sigma V^T$, assuming that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. So we have a full SVD, $U^T U = I$, $V^T V = I$, and $\Sigma$ is diagonal with nonnegative entries. I mention this because everything is slightly different in the case of a reduced SVD.

Now if $u_i$ is the $i$th column of $U$, then $A^T u_i = V \Sigma^T U^T u_i$. $U^T u_i = e_i$ (check it). Then $\Sigma^T e_i$ is the $i$th column of $\Sigma^T$, which is $\sigma_i e_i$ (check it). Finally $V e_i$ is the $i$th column of $V$, so we have $A^T u_i = \sigma_i v_i$.

Doing the same thing for $A$ and $v_i$, we find that $A v_i = \sigma_i u_i$, so $A A^T u_i = A \left ( \sigma_i v_i \right ) = \sigma_i^2 u_i$.

Finally, $u_i$ are unit by the definition of the SVD, so there's no need to separately prove anything there.